# AWS copilot fails to create pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a repo for all my docker stuff.

I would like to store copilot configs here as well, instead of adding a new copilot/ directory to the repo of every micro service.
As far as I know this should be possible.

So now I have one single copilot dir in a separate repo which looks like this:

```
copilot
.workspace
...
  - some-service
    - mainfest.yml
  - other-service
    - manifest.yml
```

etc. This works, I can add more services and I can deploy them.

However I tried to create a pipeline and that failed. According to the docs the pipeline should be able to handle multiple services, but I don't understand how.

I can run

```
copilot pipeline init
```

then I pushed the resulting files to my repo.

Then I tried:

```
copilot pipeline update
```

But this returns an error:

```
ACTION REQUIRED! Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/codesuite/settings/connections to update the status of connection xy-user-service from PENDING to AVAILABLE.
✘ Failed to create a new pipeline: pipeline-myApp-user-service.
✘ create pipeline: check if changeset is empty: create change set copilot-51ef519a-711b-4126-bfbd-3d618ef824a5 for stack pipeline-myApp-user-service: ValidationError: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::CodeStarConnections::Connection]
    status code: 400, request id: 8a87f62a-ae14-4fe3-9a3e-8b965d2af794: describe change set copilot-51ef519a-711b-4126-bfbd-3d618ef824a5 for stack pipeline-myApp-user-service: ValidationError: Stack [pipeline-myApp-user-service] does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 44927d7e-2514-466a-94ff-51e932042737
```

The xy-user-service connection didn't exist. The list of connections is empty. I tried to create it, linking my Bitbucket to AWS. But the error is still there..

What am I doing wrong?

Am I supposed to run `copilot app init` in the root dir of each and every micro service (they are in separate repos) and then should I create a separate pipeline for each?

Is it not possible to just store copilot configs in one place?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which region are you running in?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have one repo with all of your configs, and separate repos for each service's source code.

If this is the case, the pipeline is not working because it needs the url to the source repo, not the repo with the config files; this is how it can detect changes to the source code that trigger the pipeline.

You CAN have multiple services in one Copilot app, but if you want a single pipeline for the entire app, the microservices' source code needs to be in one repository.

See:
https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/concepts/applications/

https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/concepts/services/

https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/concepts/pipelines/

(Cross-posted from https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/2109; we primarily use GitHub Issues for Q&As.)

Thanks so much!